# Squish - No mouseclick in list

Tags: python, listview, squish

Unable to perform mouseclick/ select a item in list item.
Ex: Q1,Q2,Q3 in the list. Want to choose Q2 in the screen.

QQuicklistview is used. Also, it doesn't hold index value.

Is there any way to select/choose a item in the list?